# How to include date of last update when joining three tables with distinct sum of count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL-Server
I have three tables:

One [AD] includes a list of all actions performed by the user, including user ID [UserID] and descriptions [Description], as well as the ID of the session the description relates to [SessionID] and when the action was done [Timestamp].

````
```
UserID   Description            Timestamp         SessionID
221 Completed action item   27/01/2019 10:43    202
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:07    232
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:07    232
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:08    235
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:08    236
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:08    236
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:12    237
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:13    238
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:14    239
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:14    239
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:15    233
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:15    233
221 Completed action item   08/03/2019 07:16    240
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 09:56    331
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 09:56    331
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 09:57    332
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 09:57    332
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 09:58    333
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 09:58    333
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 09:59    334
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 09:59    334
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 10:00    335
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 10:01    336
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 10:01    336
202 Completed action item   27/03/2019 10:02    337

```
````

Each session is associated to a course. I can see the association in a second table [Sessions]. this table includes a list of all courses [CourseID] and what sessions are associated to each course [SessionID].

````
```
CourseID SessionID
46   202
62   232
62   235
72   331
72   332
73   333
````

The third table includes the user's name and email.

````
```
    UserID   FirstName        Email
    202      Buddy            sample@gmail.com
    232      John             john@gmail.com
 ```
````

I've managed to join all three tables and count how many sessions each user did for each course.

My output table includes: 
CourseID, Sum of counts per session, UserID, user name and email

Now I'd like for each row to add the last date the row was updated.
So if a user does a session today, the sum goes up (this works) and it would show today's date in the date column.

I've tried using Max(date) but I get errors no matter where I put this.
I'm sure it has to do with location in the sub queries.
I used Max([Timestamp]) or tried using

```
CAST([Timestamp] AS DATE) as 'Date'
```

and then using Max() but to no avail.

Here's what I have, without the date:

````
```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS id, 
id_user, 
u.[FirstName],
u.[Email], 
COURSEID, 
SUM(A) AS SESSIONS_DONE
FROM ( 
    SELECT  
        s.[CourseID] COURSEID
        ,count (distinct s.[SessionID]) as 'A'
        ,ad.[UserID] id_user
        FROM [Sessions] s, [AuditData] ad 
        WHERE s.[SessionID]=ad.[SessionID]
        AND ad.[Description]='Completed action item'
        GROUP BY CourseID, USERID 
        )sub
Join [Users] u on id_user=u.[UserID]
GROUP BY id, u.[FirstName], u.[Email], id_user, COURSEID, A
 --ORDER BY lastupdate
; 
```
````

as you can see, eventually i want the results to be in order of date
a sample result should look something like this:

````
```
id | COURSEID | A | id_user | lastupdate
1  | 62       | 8 | 221     | 2019-03-03 07:16:19.920
2  | 72       | 7 | 202     | 2019-03-27 10:02:12.367
3  | 42       | 1 | 221     | 2019-03-27 10:43:31.717
```
````

I can get the first four columns (plus the name and email, not represented in this table), it's the last one that I don't know how to get.
Any ideas?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a great place to start.

Comment: Sorry so long. Wanted to be as clear as possible

Comment: The length is fine. But there are three tables here and you only posted data for one of them. Also, you really should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm struggling to fully interpret your question, but I think this is what you're after?

One record per user, per course.  Each record with the user details, the course id, how many unique sessions for that course, and the timestamp of the last session on that course?

```
SELECT
  u.*,
  c.CourseID,
  c.SessionCount,
  c.LastSessionTimestamp
FROM
  Users      AS u
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    a.UserID,
    s.CourseID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.SessionID)  AS SessionCount,
    MAX(a.[Timestamp])           AS LastSessionTimestamp
  FROM
    AuditData  AS a
  INNER JOIN
    Sessions   AS s
      ON s.SessionID = a.SessionID
  WHERE
    a.Description = 'Completed action item'
  GROUP BY
    a.UserID,
    s.CourseID
)
  c
    ON u.UserID = c.UserID
```

That counts "Sessions which have a 'Completed Action Item'", rather than just sessions, but doesn't return courses which are in the table but don't have a 'Completed Action Item'.

If you want the Zeros, you may want this...

```
SELECT
  u.*,
  c.CourseID,
  c.SessionCount,
  c.LastSessionTimestamp
FROM
  Users      AS u
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    a.UserID,
    s.CourseID,
    SUM(a.hasCompletedActionItem      )  AS SessionCount,
    MAX(a.LastCompletedActionTimestamp)  AS LastSessionTimestamp
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      UserID,
      SessionID,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Description = 'Completed action item' THEN 1  ELSE  0  END)  AS hasCompletedActionItem,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Description = 'Completed action item' THEN [Timestamp] END)  AS LastCompletedActionTimestamp,
      MAX([Timestamp])                                                           AS LastTimestamp
    FROM
      AuditData  AS a
    GROUP BY
      UserID,
      SessionID
  )
    a
  INNER JOIN
    Sessions   AS s
      ON s.SessionID = a.SessionID
  GROUP BY
    a.UserID,
    s.CourseID
)
  c
    ON u.UserID = c.UserID
```

Comment: This looks so much cleaner than my query. 
But i get:
The multi-part identifier "a.UserID" could not be bound.

Comment: @Buddy - It's just practice.  You should have seen my queries in 2005.  (The error is a typo, it should be from `u`)

Comment: Works perfectly. Though for some reason i have 130 rows instead of the 51 I was expecting.
Looking into this.

Comment: I know what the issue is, we're not taking only the "Complete an action" description from the AuditData table..... So i'm getting more rows than i expected.

Comment: @Buddy Please remember to upvote and/or accept answer that helped.  *(Added the missing WHERE clause)*

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I've been working on this all day!